# win10toast can not be converted to Unicode error

Tags: python, types, unicode

So im making a program in python that basically gets specific stock prices and its able to have a notification pop-up on the computer in which the program is running on displaying that specific price. But I get a error when I do it. Heres my code and error.

```
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si

from yahoo_fin.stock_info import get_analysts_info, get_company_info, get_company_officers, get_currencies, get_top_crypto
user_input = input("Company(refer as stock name): ")
stock_price = si.get_live_price(user_input)

toast = ToastNotifier()
toast.show_toast("test",stock_price, duration=20)
```

And heres my error

```
  File "c:\Users\dilly\Downloads\notifier\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    toast.show_toast("test",stock_price, duration=20)
  File "C:\Users\dilly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win10toast\__init__.py", line 127, in show_toast
    self._show_toast(title, msg, icon_path, duration)
  File "C:\Users\dilly\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\win10toast\__init__.py", line 107, in _show_toast
    Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, (self.hwnd, 0, NIF_INFO,
TypeError: Objects of type 'numpy.float64' can not be converted to Unicode.
```

Comment: Maybe you should convert `stock_price` to a string.

Comment: @MarkRansom how would i do that?

Comment: There are lots of ways.  The simplest is `str(stock_price)`.

Comment: @MarkRansom it works thank you so much. Would you mind putting it as a answer so i can mark it right and if someone else comes upon this issue they can figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `can not be converted to Unicode` error means the code was expecting a string but got something else.

The easiest way to fix it is to directly convert the object to a string.

```
toast.show_toast("test", str(stock_price), duration=20)
```

The more modern approach is [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) which allow you to place the value inside another string if you want and apply optional [formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).  For example:

```
toast.show_toast("test", f"Price: {stock_price:0.2f}", duration=20)
```